# Excel drop down disappeares after deleting rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation, dropdownlist

I have created a drop down using data validation list. The issue is that when I delete rows the drop down in my cells also gets deleted. Is there any way tor retain the drop down ? I delete rows because my sheet has validation for mandatory columns also so sometimes it gives me error pop up even though the row is empty. I then delete the rows and then my validation works fine.

Comment: How about clear the row directly instead of remove it?

Comment: I did but still my validation error pops up. Maybe the data doesn't get clear up properly. I had to delete the rows then

Comment: Is there any other way to get a "permanent" drop down ?

Comment: @Anonymous,, instead of `Drop Down`, use `Combo box,, (Developer Tab,, Active X control)`,, Excel will not remove it as soon you remove the ROW. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS thanks it worked great but what if i want the same combo box for the entire column or for a cell range ?

Comment: @Anonymous, Combo box is different than Drop Down,, and it's no practical approach that you create Drop down for Column and Delete the Row/Rows next day,,, perfect planning is required !!

Comment: @RajeshS the sheet will be used by end users and they need to delete rows in some scenarios